# Using PDO with other classes

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I have been forcing myself to get into more OOP. I have hated it all up in till now. When i am using some simple prepare statment in PDO within another class as a method it never works. I resolved it by doing the obvious: globalising the PDO object into the method. It works, and does what i want - but if i had many many methods from loads of different classes, adding "global $db;" as the first line to alllll the functions/methods it seems quite tedious. Is there a way of integrating PDO into all classes? or at least each class- instead of every single bloody method?

Heres a very very simple example of what what curretnly works, but as i said tedious:

```
<?php
 $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=blaa;", "blaa", "blaa");
class test{

function show($col, $id){
    global $db;
    $result = $db->prepare("SELECT ".$col." FROM products WHERE id = :id");
    $result->execute(array("id"=>$id));
    $row = $result->fetch();
    echo $row[$col];
}
}

$show = new test();
$show->show("price", 1);
?>
```

..so i can use my PDO in the method "show()" but if i were to add another method, i would have to put "global $db;" in it again...

So how do i not globalise it in just a method, but instead, ALL CLASSES?
I tried inheriting the PDO class into the "test" class but that did not work; I tried using a constructor like:

```
<?php
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=blaa;", "blaa", "blaa");
class test{
    public $db;
function __construct($db){
           $this->db = $db;
    }
function show($col, $id){
    $result = $db->prepare("SELECT ".$col." FROM products WHERE id = :id");
    $result->execute(array("id"=>$id));
    $row = $result->fetch();
    echo $row[$col];
}
}

$show = new test($db);
$show->show("price", 1);
?>
```

but that did not work..

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks 
-Wylie

Comment: In the 2nd case, $db PDO object is out of the scope of the class. public $db of the class is not same as the PDO object $db = new PDO(...). In your 2nd case, you might want to make test as an extended class of PDO. You can also look into passing object by reference.

Comment: your show function is vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: How is it vulnerable to SQL injection if its using a prepared statement...?

Comment: @user2670722 you are passing $col value directly to your query statement without any type of sanitization.

Comment: He probably means because you've put `$col` right in the SQL instead of binding it to the statement afterwards.

Comment: ooh yes, the $col.. badly done! when i tried :col and then put it in the array placeeholder it did not work... so shall i just surround $col in quote()?

Comment: just don't allow the users to send $col, it's not their job which table to query. Control it only from the code

Comment: Yea, i guess it doesnt matter anyway because its not a user input - in fact the whole example is just a simple version of what i am doing!

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->db = $db;
```

means you assigned `$db` to `$this->db`, not the contrary!

So, you have to use **$this->db**, not `$db` in your class

```
$result = $this->db->prepare("SELECT ".$col." FROM products WHERE id = :id");
```

Answer (score 1):

"Your Common Sense" is right. But I want to add that you could and should use the singleton pattern: create a class whose purpose is to maintain one unique connection to the database.

```
class Database {
    private static $instance = null;

    private $pdo;
    private function __construct() {
        $this->pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=blaa;", "blaa", "blaa");
    }

    public static function get() {
        if(is_null(self::$instance))
            self::$instance = new Database();
        return self::$instance;
    }
}
```

Then, every time you need to access the database, instead of storing the PDO object as an instance attribute, you use:

```
$db = Database::get();
```

---

Your example would become:

```
class test {
    function __construct() {
        // You don't need this anymore, unless you have other things to do in the constructor
    }

    function show($col, $id) {
        $db = Database::get();
        $result = $db->prepare("SELECT ".$col." FROM products WHERE id = :id");
        $result->execute(array("id"=>$id));
        $row = $result->fetch();
        echo $row[$col];
    }
}
```

If you don't want to call `Database::get` in every method where you need it, you could do it once in the constructor instead.

```
class test {
    private $db;

    function __construct() {
        $this->db = Database::get();
    }

    function show($col, $id) {
        $result = $this->db->prepare("SELECT ".$col." FROM products WHERE id = :id");
        $result->execute(array("id"=>$id));
        $row = $result->fetch();
        echo $row[$col];
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should clarify how to use `$db = Database::get();` in every method from now on instead of reinstancing it

Comment: Oh, that makes sense! how would $db = Database::get(); go into other classes?

Comment: It is, but still I don't see the difference between writting global $db in each method, and writting $db = database:get(), it's anti-pattern to reuse it, what if I have 50 methods with queries?

Comment: Edited again. :) There are things you can't do with the call in the constructor (such as switching to another target database transparently in the middle of the code), but if you don't need them you can save one line per method that way.

Comment: A singleton is just another form of a global variable. It should be avoided, as it makes it really hard to unit test the software if it is used. It is considered an anti-pattern by a considerable part of the programming community.

Comment: When you need a database connection to persist through the script, you don't have many choices. A singleton is still better than a plain global, as it can enforce some rules.

Comment: Only having ONE database connection to use is the exception. And there are plenty of better alternatives, all of them implementing a way of injecting the dependency.